# LineFragmentPadding for a NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

How can I know the line fragment padding a NSTextField is using ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `-lineFragmentPadding` for `NSTextField's textContainer`. Like this:

```
float lineFragmentPadding = [textContainer lineFragmentPadding];
```

For example:

```
NSSize textFieldSize = [textFieldOutlet frame].size;
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:[textFieldOutlet attributedStringValue]] autorelease];
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(textFieldSize.width, textFieldSize.height)] autorelease];
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[[NSLayoutManager alloc] init] autorelease];

[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

[layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];

float lineFragmentPadding = [textContainer lineFragmentPadding];
NSLog(@"Padding: %f", lineFragmentPadding);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, one question.. How does the textContainer binds with the NSTextField? I don't see on the code a direct communication with a NSTextField object, I just see you initialize it with size info.

Comment: @TheReverend Yes, I initialize with attributes string because `NSLayoutManager` is using `NSTextContainer`. It is the way which I know how to do it.